# Highlight the active anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 navigation beside each other, they are using anchor links, i want to highlight active link once it is clicked.

What i did is

```
$('.navyy li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight').siblings('li').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

and the HTML is

```
 <div class="navyy">
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#top">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bookmark1">Usability vs Functionality</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bookmark2">99/100 Google PageSpeed!</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="nav">
     <li><a href="#bookmark3">Gravatar Caching!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bookmark4">Optimize Images First!</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bookmark5">Rich Snippets Boost CTR</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

It seems the jQuery is just active on of the `UL` if you click on one of the item in first nav it will be highlight, but if you select another item from other nav the first selected item will be remain highlighted.

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLeQy/87/) example

Thanks

Comment: Because they are not siblings and ids are singular.

Comment: @epascarello Gotcha, is there any way to detect the url by hashtag and then highlight the anchor links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $navyyLi = $(".navyy li");

$navyyLi.click(function() {
  $navyyLi.removeClass('highlight')
  $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hLeQy/94/)**

Comment: Only issue with this is if there is more lis on the page that is not in the nav. Better to use `".navyy li"` inside.

Comment: ...queries the DOM for "li" on every click. Not efficient.

Comment: @epascarello and Jason: thanks for your comments, the code has been updated and improved.

Comment: @Moshtaf Change the event to use $navvyli instead of querying the DOM again.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to other answers, but more efficient. jQuery isn't having to query the DOM on each click. In this case, the elements are cached for future use.

```
var naavy = $(".navyy li");

naavy.click(function() {
    naavy.removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLeQy/89/

If you don't need to support old browsers, you can easily do it without jQuery:

```
var naavy = document.querySelectorAll(".navyy li");
var length = naavy.length;

for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    naavy[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        highlight(this);
    });
}

function highlight(element) {
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
       naavy[i].classList.remove("highlight");
    }

    element.classList.add("highlight");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLeQy/90/

Answer (score 1):

Elements are sibling only if they have the same parent so you are only removing the highlight class from `LI` elements with the same `UL` parent.  If you want to remove all the highlights no matter where they are, you can do that first.  The only problem would be if you animate on adding the highlight, then you should check that it isn't already highlighted first.  ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/gb048cam/))

```
$('.navyy li').click(function() {
    $('.navyy li').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```